# Is it possible to install Detox for testing on Ubuntu?

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, automated-tests, ubuntu-20.04, detox

I've try to find a step by step setup information to do testing with detox on ubuntu, but I've only found it for mac, and some websites says that it's necessary a mac environment.

Answer (score 0):

`detox` can be installed through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install detox
```

Comment: this is the utility clean up filenames, but the one that I'm looking for is the detox for testing in reactive native apps